# Pushing data to firebase from AWS Lambda won't work unless there is a delay on the callback

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, aws-lambda

See below code.  I'm working on an AWS lambda function that will push data to a firebase database.  My problem is that the only way I've been able to get it to work is to put a setTimeout on the callback function inside of my handler.  I don't understand why this is required.  Doesn't the request get sent off to firebase before the callback starts.

This doesn't work.

```
var admin = require("firebase-admin");

admin.initializeApp({
  credential: admin.credential.cert("./info.json"),
  databaseURL: "https://app.firebaseio.com"
});

exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {
    let x = admin.database().ref(`/12851/Winners`);
    x.push(525555);
    callback(null, {Winner: true});
};
```

This does work though.

```
var admin = require("firebase-admin");

admin.initializeApp({
  credential: admin.credential.cert("./info.json"),
  databaseURL: "https://app.firebaseio.com"
});

exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {
    let x = admin.database().ref(`/12851/Winners`);
    x.push(525555);
    setTimeout(()=>{
        callback(null, {Winner: true});
    },1500)
};
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Wire into a `.then` instead since `.push` returns a promise:

```
var admin = require("firebase-admin");

admin.initializeApp({
  credential: admin.credential.cert("./info.json"),
  databaseURL: "https://app.firebaseio.com"
});

exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {
    let x = admin.database().ref(`/12851/Winners`);
    x.push(525555).then(function(){
        callback(null, {Winner: true});
    });
};
```

Comment: Thanks!! Had no idea there was a promise available for push.  I was struggling with that all weekend!